# Xamarin C#: how to add resource to intentfilter metadata for USB connection Receiver

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, usb

This XML file named "UsbFilter" Is saved in "Resources/xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <usb-accessory model="EVK1105" manufacturer="Atmel" version="1.0"/>
</resources>
```

I now want to use this for my intentfilters metadata when a usb accessory is connected to my phone so I do this at the top of my broadcast receiver implementation:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "UsbConnectReciever")]
    [IntentFilter(new[]
    {
        UsbManager.ActionUsbAccessoryAttached
    })]
    [MetaData(UsbManager.ActionUsbAccessoryAttached, Resource = "xml/UsbFilter")]
```

However when it tries to build I get this error:

```
String types not allowed (at 'resource' with value 'xml/UsbFilter).
```

But its not a string really!
If I try with the "@" I get this error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/UsbFilter).
```

So how can I make this work?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it not only needs the '@' but it has to be all lowercase as well